# Mesh becomes obscured after applying subdivision modifier

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

so I have just started a blender tutorial with blender Guru on YouTube. I hear he is quite well known in this community.

We are making Donuts!

The issue I am having is that after applying the subdivision modifier on the icing model(which is hidden in the editing view) the mesh seems to have receded into the body of the donut or it is being partially obscured somehow.

Blender Guru himself had this issue in the tutorial however he seemed to be able to correct the problem by selecting individual vertices in the affected areas.

I have tried to do the same myself but I cant seem to select any. Selecting vertices on the edge of the affected area doesn't resolve the issue but selecting and pressing G does, however this also massively distorts the shape of the donut after left clicking no matter how still I keep the mouse.

Any help with this would be highly appreciated as its preventing me from manipulating the object properly.

Here is the tutorial video the part I am at is 8:32.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1isb0x4zYw&list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD&index=4

[image]

Comment: I mean that is normal, I am not sure what is he teaching you in those tutorials but Subdivision will deform your object a little to make it look smooth, It is normal for it to bend into another object that is the same... You have to simply repair it either with proportional editing as he did or use shrinkwrap (but that is little more advanced for those tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect that just selecting something will solve the issue? No, you HAVE to move things around.

When it comes to your issue with the dough getting deformed when you move the icing mesh parts around, that's most likely due to you having [Proportional Edit](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html) enabled.
I suppose it would still help to have it enabled to make the icing editing easier, so I'd suggest you to just enable its `Connected Only` mode, so that when you select mesh parts from the icing, only the remaining icing mesh parts will be affected by the Proportional Edit.

Comment: Thank you, that does help. I've also found that the mesh doesn't disappear if I don't deform the donut until after applying the subdivision.

Comment: The mesh doesn't disappear, it's just that subdivide modifiers are by default set to display both the resulting deformed mesh + the original mesh at the same time - but the result mesh is higher priority in display. It is made so that you know what is going on both before and after the modifier. Don't apply your modifier to "fix" that, it's like taking down a house's wall to see the next room. Either change the modifier display mode to something that better suits you, or learn to work with it this way.